# How to detect an object in a trigger?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I’ve placed in the scene an object with a trigger and I want the console sends me a message detecting if the player is in or out of the trigger when I click a button . When I play, it only sends me a message when the player is into the trigger.

**Code:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MapDetect : MonoBehaviour {


     void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
     {
         if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
             Debug.Log ("Map ON");

         } 
         else {
             if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
                  Debug.Log ("Map OFF");
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Your conditions are identical. If the second is true, then the first will also be true, meaning the second will never run due to the nature of if/else statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `OnTriggerEnter` and `OnTriggerExit` instead of `OnTriggerStay` to keep the current state:

```
public class MapDetect : MonoBehaviour {

    private bool isTriggered;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
            isTriggered = true;
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
            isTriggered = false;
    }

    void Update(){
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)){
            Debug.Log(isTriggered);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should do it. Although use, [`gameObject.CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.CompareTag.html) isntead of `gameObject.tag==`.

Comment: Also worth noting: since you're only interested in the player, you could put your trigger on a layer that _only_ collides with the player (assuming the player is also on such a layer). That way, you don't need the tag check and the physics calculations become cheaper.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ludovic. But how can I do if the button is an UI button of the canvas instead of the key space? And I want to appears a message in the canvas with "Map on"/"Map off".

Comment: @Angelsm That's another question, it would be too long to answer in the comments. Ask another question and post the link here so i can try to answer :)

Comment: Ok, I'm going to do another question.

Comment: @Ludovic Here is the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632196/how-add-a-message-in-the-canvas-if-the-player-is-in-out-a-trigger

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is totally wrong. You're only checking if the **TRIGGER STAYS IN YOUR BOUNDS** but still trying to log *"Map OFF"* message which will never happen.

Instead of `OnTriggerStar` method use `OnTriggerEnter` and `OnTriggerExit`. Then print the message only when needed ( or in debug mode ) :

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if ( other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") )
    {
        m_IsPlayerOnTheMap = true;
    } 
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if( other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") )
    {
        m_IsPlayerOnTheMap = false;
    }
}

void Update()
{
#if DEBUG
    if ( m_IsPlayerOnTheMap )
    {
        Debug.Log("Map ON");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Map OFF");
    }
#endif
}

private bool m_IsPlayerOnTheMap = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MapDetect : MonoBehaviour {


 void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
 {
     if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
     {
         Debug.Log ("Map ON");
     } 
 }

 void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
 {
     if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
     {
         Debug.Log ("Map OFF");
     }
 }
}
```

This will switch it on when you enter and off when you exit (althout all it does right now is print the result).

Hope it helps.