# How do I identify objects that enter a trigger?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers

How would I write a code to identify objects that enter a trigger in Unity3d? (eg. An object named, "Cube", enters a trigger. The trigger then displays, "Cube", in the Debug tab.)

Comment: If you copy the title of this question into Google search bar, you will find many solution. Not sure why you didn't do that.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42627702/2938526

Comment: void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){ string name = other.gameobject.name;} . Even basic research would have yield an answer to this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect an object in a trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42627581/how-to-detect-an-object-in-a-trigger)

Comment: Post also the inspector values for the object that is the trigger and the object that should trigger it. The question also has to be migrated to Gamedev SE.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    Debug.Log(other.gameObject.name);
}
```

A simple Google search would likely suffice for this question, but there's the code for it anyway.

That code should be in a Monobehaviour script on the GameObject that is being collided with (E.g, a wall).

More on this here: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/colliders-triggers